# Adjusting the proof of Maximum Modulus Thm. version III to prove a question?

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Here is the statement of the question I am trying to proof:

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open set in the complex plane, $f$ is an analytic function in $\Omega$ and $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |f(z_n)| \leq M$$ for every sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $\Omega$ which converges to a boundary point of $\Omega.$ Prove that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $z \in \Omega.$

Here is the statement and the proof of the Maximum Modulus Thm. version III:

> [image]

Could anyone tell me how can we adjust the proof of Maximum Modulus Thm. version  III to prove this question,please?

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:proof-writing] or with [tag:complex-integration]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It can be considered as writing a proof for the question I want ...... it has nothing to do with complex integration but I assumed that people who know complex integration  may know MMT as well